# Which are the synchronous interfaces of Java RMI?

Tags: java, rmi

I've been asked to cite the main Java RMI synchronous interfaces; but I have literally no clue about it because I've never worked with RMI. 
I've checked the APIDocs related to the `RMIConnection` class and the `Remote` class but I don't know if methods such as `invoke()` or `lookup()` are synchronous.

Comment: The question is meaningless. *All* of RMI is synchronous, by definition.